# Rails 5 Нow to update part of the page?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-5

Now I'm doing this:

in *.html:

```
<div class="inside"></div>
<%= link_to 'inside', homes_inside_path , remote:true%>
```

in controller

```
def inside
  tmp = 'hello world'
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render partial: 'loader',locals: {selector:'.inside',partial:'inside', local_var: tmp}}
  end
end
```

in loader.js.erb

```
$('<%= selector %>').html("<%= j( render(partial: partial, locals: {local_var:local_var})) %>");
```

in inside.html.erb

```
<div class="t">local_var</div>
```

result: contents of the file "inside.html.erb" is inserted to class "inside". 
But if you want to pass more than one parameter is very inconvenient. We have to do a lot of different file "loader". The "rails 5" there is possible to update parts of the page. How to use it?

Comment: Take a look at Turbolinks as well - just a sidenote

Comment: I looked at turbolink (https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks), but no examples with Rails did not understand ((